# Regular expression to find last dot in request URI

Tags: regex, apache

I am trying to write a regular expression for apache virtual host configuration that will map request if URI doesn't have certain extensions. Below expression I have written.

```
^\/bookdata\/.+\.(?!jpg|mp3|mp4|zip|doc|pdf|xls|xlsx).*$
```

Below URI is not matching to this expression which is perfectly fine.

```
/bookdata/rw0/media/Q2e_00_RW_U08_Q_Classroom.mp3?fd=1
```

My problem with below URI which is matching with this expression due to two dots.

```
/bookdata/rw0/media/ELM2_U02_Track06_Chart2.8.mp3?fd=1
```

Any small help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the neg. lookahead right at the start, like so

```
^(?!.*\.(?:jpg|mp3|mp4|zip|doc|pdf|xls|xlsx))\/bookdata\/.+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XBtEu6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

As I know request URI doesn't contain request params(after question mark)
So you can ommit .* at the end of your regex then you can match your prefer uris.
This happen because you say that your uri end by those extension must not match.